# Validate an Entity through an API with Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I have an entity with simple fields. Unfortunately, I can't say what are the validation constraint on the Symfony side. I must post these information on an API route. If it returns no error message, I can validate the entity, if not, I have to display the error messages to the user.

If I want to do it dirty, it's quite easy but I would like to use the Validator.

When I do the `$form->isValid`, I would like to have this API call done and add the error messages directly to the form.

At the moment I have something like

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    if ($entityModelManager->validate($form)) {
        //the entity is valid here
    }
}
```

But as I said, I think this is dirty, I would like to have a better code.

Answer (score 1):

1) Setup entity constraints:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#the-basics-of-validation

2) Use ValidatorInterface
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service

ex:

```
public function create(ValidatorInterface $validator)
{
    $post = new Post();
    // ... 
    $errors = $validator->validate($post);
    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            // ... write error to API errors output
        }
    }

    // .. save entity & return success
}
```

BTW: i don't understand relation between api and symfony forms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but ... this does not answer my problem. I don't have the constraints on the Symfony side so it's not possible for me to setup the constraints in the entity.